# How can I print "<" or ">" sequence in L" "

Tags: c++, msxml

Build in c++
How can I print "<" or ">" sequence in L" "

```
...
IXMLDOMDocument *pXMLDom = NULL;
...

createTextNode(L"<!--  <example>  -->",pXMLDom)
```

Comment: Looks to me you just did it!

Comment: Well, call me old-school, but I found that if I use my favourite search engine to look for the phrase `msxml create comment`, the [first search result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms765449(v=vs.85)) looks quite relevant.